# ACF insert logo from option page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using the plugin ACF
I want to insert from an options page, the logo in the header of all pages
I can not get the image url

```
<?php $logo = get_field( 'logo', 'option' ); ?>
<?php if ( $logo ) : ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

What is the right method?
thank you

Comment: Your code seems fine to me... Check if you properly configured your `logo` field return value as _Image Array_. Also, what's exactly the issue here? Is your `img` tag rendering with a wrong `src` value or you don't even get inside the condition?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. Make sure the image "Return Value" is set to "Image Array" in ACF settings.

```
<?php
    $website_logo = get_field('website_logo', 'option');
    if( !empty($website_logo) ):
?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $website_logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $website_logo['alt']; ?>"></a>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but a fix it.

First I put the ACF "logo" in a page, then a use the ID of this page to put the logo in header, at last I call the logo in header.php like this:

```
<?php
$logo = get_field('logo', 5); // 5 is the ID of the page where I put the logo
$size = 'full';
?>

<div id="logo" style="padding-top:10px;"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $logo, $size ); ?></div>
```

Enjoy!